# Regex If a line contains

Tags: regex

I am new to Regex, but here is what I have and what I am trying to do:
If line contains AAA: BBB request valid
If line AAA: contains CCC than DDD needs to be in another line for the request to be valid

Here is what I have

```
   `(AAA:.*?\bBBB\b)|(AAA:.*?\bCCC\b)(.*?\bDDD=.*?([0-9A-Za-z_-])\b)
```

Here is what I tried but does not work
http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html

Also, with the IF statements do you need an action like other programming languages?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain your question more clearly .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to match `AAA: BBB` and `AAA: CCC` if followed by `DDD` on the next line. Instead of `.*?`, you could just have `\r?\n`.

```
(AAA:\s+\bBBB\b|AAA:\s+\bCCC\b\r?\n\bDDD\b)
```

**[Here's a live preview](https://regex101.com/r/P2tFOU/1)**

As you can see, it only matches `AAA: CCC` if it's followed by `DDD`.

[image]

Comment: What if line DDD is above AAA:CCC?

Comment: [Just add it like any other condition](https://regex101.com/r/P2tFOU/2)

Comment: Ok that works but what if it is more than 1line and can change amount each request

Comment: The code you put only works if DDD is 1 new line above or under AAA:CCC

Comment: Yes, because that's what you said in the question.

Comment: Ok sorry what if there are many newlines between AAA:CCC and DDD

Comment: Then instead of `\r?\n` use `(?:\r?\n)+`. [Take a look here](https://regex101.com/r/P2tFOU/3).

Comment: Works great but if there are letters or spaces on any other lines between them it does not work See the 1 and d [Look Here](https://regex101.com/r/P2tFOU/4)